# Cannot configure proxyPass for glassfish admin console

Tags: apache, glassfish, admin, mod-proxy

I've got the following situation.

There is an apache 2.2 server and glassfish 3.1.2 running behind it. All requests to port 80 are redirected to glassfish server through mod_proxy.

This is what I wrote in the httpd.conf:

```
ProxyPass / http://some_server:8080
ProxyPassReverse / http://some_server:8080
```

where some_server is the the domain name of my server.

It works fine and I can see that the requests to port 80 are redirected to glassfish instance.

The problem is that I need to setup similar thing for accessing the admin console of the glassfish. The reason is that the port 4848 is closed from external access and as far as I understand I can solve this problem using mod_proxy. This is what I tried to do:

```
ProxyPass /admin http://some_server:4848
ProxyPassReverse /admin http://some_server:4848
```

But it doesn't work. It redirects to the login page of the admin console but nothing is displayed.

Any ideas how I can solve my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admin console works under secure connection.

You probably need to add this to your apache virtual server config:

```
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile your_cert_file
    SSLCertificateKeyFile your_cert_key_file
    SSLCertificateChainFile your_authority_cert_file
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have the same problem but with Nginx as reverse proxy. Does any one knows a solution for Nginx?